# How to fix gitk not refreshing properly on Big Sur?

Tags: mac, git

I have recently updated to Big Sur and now my favourite git graph viewer, gitk, isn't refreshing or re-drawing well on load or after certain interactions.

Gitk is written in tcl and seems to run using 'wish'. I have the latest [tcl-tk](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/tcl-tk) package installed from Homebrew already so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

I realise tcl-tk is a pretty old thing to get running on MacOS in some ways but I dearly love this viewer and have to use MacOS for work. It functioned well enough on Catalina.

Can anyone suggest a fix or approach that might work?